# Wrapping and centering title in R

Tags: r

I have a long title that incorporates italics. I tried using `\n` to move half of the title onto a new line with limited success. I have it mostly figured out, but now I can't center the second line.

```
title(main=expression(paste("Inoculated \n", italic("Petunia x hybrida\n"), "`Dreams Red` mortality\n as a function of irrigation treatment" )))
```

[image: Graph with title issue]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `atop`, which is actually for formatting math, but is frequently used for this purpose. It puts its first argument on the top and its second on the bottom, so `paste` as necessary.

```
plot(x = rnorm(10))
title(main = expression(atop(paste('Inoculated ', italic("Petunia x hybrida"), 
                                   "`Dreams Red` mortality"), 
                             "as a function of irrigation treatment")))
```

[image: plot with centered title]

Comment: `atop` doesn't require `bquote`. It doesn't hurt in this case, but `expression` is a bit safer.

Comment: I'll edit. I think I had a case like this where `expression` wouldn't cut it, so I've been using `bquote` instead...but maybe I shouldn't; I should read the docs.

Comment: `bquote` returns a 'call'-object and the result fails the `is.expression` test. Most applications don't care but I have run across some that do. There are definitely instances where `bquote` is much more convenient than `expression`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The formatting presented here is what would be most appropriate for my needs. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I counted three "\n"'s in that expression so I guess you want 4 lines of title. That's fairly easy with nested used of plotmath `atop`:

```
title(main=expression(atop( atop(Inoculated, 
                                 italic("Petunia x hybrida")),
                            atop("\'Dreams Red\'"~mortality, 
                                 'as a function of irrigation treatment') )))
```

I was also guessing you actually didn't want backticks and so escaped single-quotes.

[image]

The task of 'writing' to a graphics device with an expression containing a number of lines not a power of 2 is a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try the atop function to see if I can get the formatting necessary